# Delete one record between two tables in 1: n design

Tags: mysql

I have two table in MySql Database. I am pretty sure if those have a relation 1 : n
This is those table :
First table named tb_karyawan *(karyawan in english is employee)*

```
MariaDB [db_egi]> select * from tb_karyawan where  NIK_KARYAWAN = 2;
+--------------+------------------+---------------+-------+-------------+-------+
| NIK_KARYAWAN | NAMA             | TGL_BERGABUNG | LEVEL | DEPARTEMENT | KELAS |
+--------------+------------------+---------------+-------+-------------+-------+
|            2 | Nurrahmi Massere | 2016-02-02    |     5 |           6 |     3 |
+--------------+------------------+---------------+-------+-------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The second table named : tb_master_perhitungan :

```
MariaDB [db_egi]> select * from tb_master_perhitungan;
+----+---------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| ID | PERIODE             | NIK_KARYAWAN | ID_C1 | ID_C2 | ID_C3 | ID_C4 | ID_C5 | STATUS     |
+----+---------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| 13 | 2016-02-07 12:07:00 |            2 |     1 |     3 |     3 |     2 |     3 | UNAPPROVED   |
| 13 | 2016-01-07 09:00:28 |            2 |     2 |     3 |     3 |     2 |     3 | APPROVED   |
| 13 | 2015-12-07 15:47:18 |            2 |     3 |     3 |     3 |     2 |     3 | APPROVED   |

+----+---------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please see of the field : NIK_KARYAWAN.
The relation is : there are one record in tb_karyawan that related to a lot of record in tb_master_perhitungan.
I set the relation in HeidiSQL like this :

```
| KEY NAME                              | COLUMN        | REFERENCE    | FOREIGN COLUMN   | ON UPDATE  |  ON DELETE  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FK_tb_master_perhitungan_tb_karyawan  | NIK_KARYAWAN  | tb_karyawan  | NIK_KARYAWAN     | CASCADE    |  NO ACTION  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

On UPDATE is good but in delete I got a problem.
The problem is, when I decide to delete one row in tb_karyawan, which is `NIK_KARYAWAN = 2`, I want to still hold the record in tb_master_perhitungan that have a relation with this `NIK_KARYAWAN = 2` even `NIK_KARYAWAN = 2` has been deleted in tb_karyawan.
This is the error :

```
Error Number: 1451

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_egi`.`tb_master_perhitungan`, CONSTRAINT `FK_tb_master_perhitungan_tb_karyawan` FOREIGN KEY (`NIK_KARYAWAN`) REFERENCES `tb_karyawan` (`NIK_KARYAWAN`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)

DELETE FROM `tb_karyawan` WHERE `NIK_KARYAWAN` = '2'
```

Should I change the design or there is another solution ?
Any solution is so appreciated.

Comment: Set `ON DELETE` to `CASCADE` instead of `No Action`

Answer (score 1):

In the second table you have to make foreign key constraint, ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE.
as like suppose i have two table jobseeker and job_status and one foreign key between them so foreign key setup will be like :-

```
CONSTRAINT `job_status_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`jobseeker_id`)
REFERENCES `jobseeker` (`jobseeker_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 0):

No action relation in mysql restrict the action the same as restrict, so when you want to delete record with the primary key from your master table you must delete all related records within the foreign keys table before.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: So, what should I do ?
Changing the design? 
His case is, if an employee was fired, (1st table)
I want to keep the employee data still exist (2nd table). Or should I create a new table to store data ?

Comment: No, you didn't need second table. you can remove the relation.